# different ways of compilation cause the same dynamic library generate differents results

Tags: c, gcc, cmake

I use different ways of compilation to compile my project for testing symbol of a same cover when loaded dynamic library, however, there are two different results in different compilations, I cannot find differences between this two compilations, please help?

when I use `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`， I see official description of `dlsym()` as below:

> The `dlsym()` function shall search for the named symbol in all objects
>   loaded automatically as a result of loading the object referenced by
>   handle (see `dlopen()`). Load ordering is used in `dlsym()` operations
>   upon the global symbol object. The symbol resolution algorithm used
>   shall be dependency order as described in `dlopen()`.

**Note:** load ordering is an mechanism to handle conflict when loaded symbols with same name.
So I want to run a test for `load ordering`, however, I find different results when use different compilations(as I think two of them are equivalent)

here is my project:

### file tree:

├── CMakeLists.txt

├── fn.c

└── main.c

### CMakeLists.txt

```
project(demo)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -fpic ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
add_library(fn SHARED fn.c)

add_executable(demo main.c)
target_link_libraries(demo -ldl)
```

### fn.c

```
#include<stdio.h>


int temp = 1;
void fn_print(){
    printf("fn  temp address is %p, value is %d\n",  &temp, temp);

}
```

### main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dlfcn.h>

typedef void (*fn_p)();
int temp = 0;

int main(){
    printf("main temp address is %p, value is %d\n",  &temp, temp);

    void *handle = dlopen("./libfn.so", RTLD_NOW);
    fn_p dy_print = dlsym(handle, "fn_print");
    dy_print();

return 0;
}
```

First, I use cmake to compile this project and test, we can see variable temp share the same address 0x60104c and value 0 in obj file and dynamic library.

```
root@acnszavl00033:~/temp/dylib_test# cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /root/temp/dylib_test
root@acnszavl00033:~/temp/dylib_test# make
Scanning dependencies of target demo
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/demo.dir/main.c.o
[ 50%] Linking C executable demo
[ 50%] Built target demo
Scanning dependencies of target fn
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/fn.dir/fn.c.o
[100%] Linking C shared library libfn.so
[100%] Built target fn
root@acnszavl00033:~/temp/dylib_test# ./demo
main temp address is 0x60104c, value is 0
fn  temp address is 0x60104c, value is 0
```

according to description, varaible `temp` should have different addresses, then I use gcc to only recompile demo(don't make changes to dynamic library libfn.so) , then test, varaible `temp` have different addresses, why?

```
root@acnszavl00033:~/temp/dylib_test# gcc -o demo main.c -ldl
root@acnszavl00033:~/temp/dylib_test# ./demo
main temp address is 0x60104c, value is 0
fn  temp address is 0x7f795cec0028, value is 1
```

I expect output of compilatoin using cmake should like this:

```
main temp address is 0x60104c, value is 0
fn  temp address is 0x7f795cec0028, value is 1
```

Comment: In case of building the project with CMake, you may always run `make VERBOSE=1` for check **actual parameters** passed to a compiler and a linker. Then you may compare these parameters with ones you use in plain command line and find the difference.

Comment: E.g. your CMake project uses `-fpic` option for compile and link the project. But your command line does not use that option.

Comment: `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS " -fpic ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")` does not have any effect because CMake treats the "*.c" files as C files, and hence, uses the C compiler, which is also visible from the output.

Answer (score 0):

The below `CMakeLists.txt` seems to solve the issue:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4)
project(demo)

add_library(fn SHARED fn.c)

add_executable(demo main.c)
target_link_libraries(demo PRIVATE dl)
```

When you don't add `cmake_minimum_required` or just provide anything below `VERSION 3.4`, you have the problem. Otherwise, when you build and run, you get the following:

```
~/so/build> cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.1.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/aytekin/so/build
~/so/build> cmake --build .
Scanning dependencies of target fn
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/fn.dir/fn.c.o
[ 50%] Linking C shared library libfn.so
[ 50%] Built target fn
Scanning dependencies of target demo
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/demo.dir/main.c.o
[100%] Linking C executable demo
[100%] Built target demo
~/so/build> ./demo 
main temp address is 0x56135a414044, value is 0
fn  temp address is 0x7f170b3cb028, value is 1
```

I am not sure if this has to do with the [policy change](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/release/3.4.html#other-changes) introduced in `v3.4`, but the most relevant change seems to be [`CMP0065`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/policy/CMP0065.html).

Comment: yeah, it really is, and I found  the essential differences between them, I add `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON)` to trace whole process, and found compile options with no `version 3.4` will have a extra one `-rdynamic` (all is /usr/bin/cc     CMakeFiles/demo.dir/main.c.o  -o demo -rdynamic -ldl ), this option will add symbols to section `.dynsym` of elf file, when dynamic loader load a dynamic library will collect all elf files' symbols in .dynamic (according to load ordering , if a symbol has been collected then it will be ignore) , then dynamic loader redirects symbols according this table

Comment: @ishen I am glad that this has solved the problem. Please think of marking it as the answer unless there is something left out.